# Xamarin replace image imageview resource in listview

Tags: listview, xamarin.android, android-imageview

I'm beginner in Xamarin. I have a Listview, there are one textview and one imageview in each row. I wrote adatpter for it, activity, everything. My goal is, when I click an item in the listview, image changes to other one.

Data class:

```
class otherLabelListData
{
    private string otherLabel;
    private int image;

    public otherLabelListData(string otherLabel, int image)
    {
        this.otherLabel = otherLabel;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public string OtherLabel
    {
        get { return otherLabel; }
    }

    public int Image
    {
        get { return image; }
    }
}
```

Here is the holder class:

```
class otherHolder
{
    public TextView labelTxt;
    public ImageView iconImg;

    public otherHolder(View itemView)
    {
        labelTxt = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.otherMessageLabel);
        iconImg = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.otherLabelIcon);
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
class otherLabelListAdapter : BaseAdapter<otherLabelListData>
{
    private JavaList<otherLabelListData> mItems;
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public otherLabelListAdapter(Context context, JavaList<otherLabelListData> items)
    {
        this.mItems = items;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return mItems.Get(position);
    }


    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return mItems.Size();
        }
    }


    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }


    public override otherLabelListData this[int position]
    {
        get
        {
            return mItems[position];
        }
    }


    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        if(inflater == null)
        {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        }

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.OtherLabelViewRow, parent, false);
        }

        otherHolder holder = new otherHolder(convertView);
        holder.labelTxt.Text = mItems[position].OtherLabel;
        holder.iconImg.SetImageResource(mItems[position].Image);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

The activity:

```
[Activity(Label = "Activity1", MainLauncher = false, Theme = "@style/Theme.Mt")]
public class Activity_OtherScreen : Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity
{
    private ListView mListView;
    private otherLabelListAdapter adapter;
    JavaList<otherLabelListData> list;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Other_Layout);

        mListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.otherList);

        adapter = new otherLabelListAdapter(this, getOthers());

        mListView.Adapter = adapter;

        mListView.ItemClick += MListView_ItemClick;
    }


    private JavaList<otherLabelListData> getOthers()
    {
        list = new JavaList<otherLabelListData>();

        otherLabelListData ot;

        ot = new otherLabelListData("Label 1", Resource.Drawable.send2display);
        list.Add(ot);

        ot = new otherLabelListData("Label 2", Resource.Drawable.send2display);
        list.Add(ot);

        ot = new otherLabelListData("Label 3", Resource.Drawable.send2display);
        list.Add(ot);

        return list;
    }

    private void MListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //..
        ???
    }
}
```

I've tried more solution, but images don't chgange in real when I click.
Please, give me any idea!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it whne you click, you have to add a click event when instanciating the convertView item, like this :

```
 public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.OtherLabelViewRow, parent, false);
        convertView.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            int p = (int)(sender as View).Tag;
            ChangeImageResource(convertView, p);
        };
    }
    convertView.Tag = position;
}

void ChangeImageResource(View convertView, int position)
{
    otherHolder holder = new otherHolder(convertView);
    holder.iconImg.SetImageResource(mItems[position].Image);
}
```

It is important that you add the click event when instanciating the convertView, so there is only one by item in your listview. Then, the Tag thing is to avoid incorrect calling. If your listview is containing many items and that you have to scroll, it may causes error in position as it's changing when scrolling. Using the tag method, you ensure that you call the right one.

Comment: Ok, in this case it's not necessary to use this method `MListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)` in activity?

Comment: No, as you're defining the click event directly in your adapter, you don't need to call the listener in the activity.